# Не работает подсветка синтаксиса xml с русскими тегами

Tags: дефект

Подсветка есть:

```
<root attr="value"/>
```

Подсветки нет:

```
<корень аттр="значение"/>
```

Обидно, э? А как же юникод?

Явное указание языка с помощью `<!-- language: xml -->` не помогает.

Полагаю, это нужно переадресовать разрабам основного SO.

Comment: Баги подсветки синтаксиса разрабы предлагают отправлять напрямую авторам библиотеки.

Comment: @Nofate дайте адрес, пожалуйста.

Comment: @alexolut [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), [Stack Exchange does not have its own syntax highlighting engine. It uses Google Code Prettify.](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)